# React Native How to store and process JSON data?

Tags: json, react-native

I am a total beginner in React Native programming. I've had a difficulty finding a tutorial explaining how to do this.

I am fetching a bus schedule data from a web API.

#### I want to do the following.

1. Store JSON data inside a variable or something.
2. Run a function on that JSON data to return appropriate bus data

#### I have two questions regarding this.

1. How can I store JSON data inside a variable or locally somehow?
2. If I want to run a JavaScript function on the JSON data, where do I do it? Inside a separate component's render() function?

#### What I've tried

I declared `let jsondata` outside of the class.
Inside `componentDidMount` I stored `responseJson` to `jsondata` using an anonymous function. When I console.log it there, it shows the JSON data properly.

However, when I try to `{console.log(jsondata)}` after `Flatlist`, it returns `undefined` while `"Hello"` logs correctly.

Why is it behaving this way? How can I use the jsondata?

#### Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

let jsondata;
export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true}

    }

    // make an API call in the beginning
    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18o9sd')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.shosfc.weekday[7]
                }, function(){
                    jsondata = responseJson;
                    // console.log(jsondata)
                });

            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 50}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:50}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.min}</Text>}
                    // keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}

                />
                {console.log(jsondata)}
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `jsondata` in `state` as well with `this.setState` and use `this.state.jsondata` in your render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How can I store JSON data inside a variable or locally somehow?

You can put it in a state value, and use local storage for storage.

**Status value delivery**

```js
 this.state ={ jsondata:{}}
...
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.shosfc.weekday[7],
                    jsondata = responseJson
                });
                console.log(this.state.jsondata);
              }
```

**Store data locally**

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
...

            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.shosfc.weekday[7],
                });
           AsyncStorage.setItem('jsondata', JSON,stringify(responseJson));
              }
```

2. If I want to run a JavaScript function on the JSON data, where do I do it? Inside a separate component's render() function?

I find this question difficult to understand. But the answer to this question I understand is that you can declare and use a function outside of JSON.

```js
thisfunc(){
 alert("function in Json")
}
...
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.shosfc.weekday[7],
                });
               this.thisfunc.bind(this)
              }
```

Comment: thanks I will try this. To clarify my last question first, let's say I have a function `getNextBus(jsondata)` from the bus schedule which is the `jsondata`. Then should `getNextBus(jsondata)` be outside of class? or inside of class?
Also, since I will be running this function multiple times throughout the day, I assume it is more appropriate for me to store `jsondata` using Async rather than passing it as a `state`?

Comment: If you want to show different data over time, not just data, you should put the time you want in the parameter.`getNextBus(thistime,jsondata)`

Comment: Hmm ultimately, I want to display the time left until the next bus (`countDownTimer`) by doing `currentTime - busTimeFromJson` (not in the code yet). In this case, should the `countDownTimer` value be inside setState? Thousand thanks again.

Comment: Using setState to display the count is not a good idea. You can use redux. Please refer https://appdividend.com/2018/08/04/react-native-redux-example-tutorial/

Comment: I know Nomadcoder!! I didnt know they have this thanks!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you choose to mark my answer with V?

Answer (score 1):

Add jsonResponse in state try this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: [],
      apiResponseJson:null
    };
  }

  // make an API call in the beginning
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18o9sd')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson.shosfc.weekday[7],
            apiResponseJson : responseJson.shosfc
          },
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 50 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.min}</Text>}
          // keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
        {console.log(this.state.apiResponseJson)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```